# Use the form values in the php without submitting and without sending query string to other page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

All the above code I saved in a page called `dum.php`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sameclass").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var QS = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
        if(QS.length>0){
            var val = QS[1].split('=');

            if(val.length>0){
                $("#edit_prdct").hide().slideDown('slow');
                //Below am adding a value to the hidden text filed
                document.getElementById('prd_id').value=val[1];
            }    
        }
    });
});
```

I had some products which i want to edit their info EDIT are the hyperlinks with the query string value

```
<DIV id="list_prdct">
    <a href="dum.php?id=1" class=sameclass>EDIT</A><BR><DIV id="edit_prdct">
    <a href="dum.php?id=2" class=sameclass>EDIT</A><BR><DIV id="edit_prdct">
    <a href="dum.php?id=3" class=sameclass>EDIT</A><BR><DIV id="edit_prdct">
    <a href="dum.php?id=4" class=sameclass>EDIT</A><BR><DIV id="edit_prdct">
</DIV>
```

In the below div I used a hidden field and I want to used its values in the mysql query in the where condition and I will display a form related to that value

```
<DIV id="edit_prdct">
    <?PHP
        $prdid"<input type=hidden id='prd_id' value=''>";
        // Here I want to use that value of the hidden field as the condition in the mysql query
    ?>
```

Comment: Just dumped your entire code here?

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Wow you made it 10x worse with that edit lol

Comment: What options do we have?

Comment: I didn't get u @Khawer Zeshan

Comment: You said `without submitting and without using Ajax and without using Query string` with using `what` you want to achieve this?

Comment: Wat i mean i dnt want to involve other page for dis purpose am sry if i said dat in  wrng way.

Comment: @SudhakarSingajogi: What do you want to achieve? Please describe you complete problem. We are unable to understand your question.

Comment: @haywire if u look at the code which i submitted i had some hyperlinks with query string and all had same class. when i click on the links i should get the query string i passed to the hyperlink and the dis should slidedown and slide up hyperlink is linked to the same page

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly, however, this is my try.

Every system has 3 parts: input, processing and output.

Here, your **PHP logic is the processing part**. It runs on the server and understands only Php. It doesnot know about your HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.

**Input is provided through HTML and Javascript(JQuery) using a web browser**. When you click a link, or submit a form, or make an Ajax call, then browser basically sends an input to the web server (its called a [HTTP Request](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp))

**Output is again HTML, CSS and Javascript**. The statements you `echo` or `print` including the ones outside `<?php ?>` tag, are all output. These are understood by a web browser and not by the server.

To send any data from client side (the web browser) to the server, you need to use [HTTP requests](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp). This can be done in 3 ways:

1. Synchronous Request(href redirects, [form submission](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), [sync. Ajax calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests), etc)
2. [Asynchronous Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) (Ajax Calls).
3. **URL redirections** (its a form of way 1 above!!)

All the ways above typically use either the GET method (query strings) or the POST method.

If you dont want to use Ajax or form submission, **you are left with only third option**, that is, call the resource links directly. For example, redirecting the user to some URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/products/134
```

where 134 is a `prod_id`.

Then on the server side, you will have to retrieve the URL and extract out prod_id from it. This is a tedious task. Fortunately we have some good frameworks to do that, like [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html), etc. But this is not the way to send data to the server in case you need to fetch data for a list of `prod_id`.

So, No, there is no other way to get data from server. Perhaps you need to remodel your problem and understand that **Php server can't know about your `prod_id` magically**, you need to send it through one of the methods of [HTTP request](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much i solvd dat by using ajax but am not feelng better bcoz i had left that without solving i chossen another way Hmmmmmmm.